# Acquire interactive shell in Packer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, packer

I'm trying to create a Packer AMI image for EC2 based off of CentOS 7. I'm able to get provisioning working just fine, I can upgrade and install packages without a hitch.

The problem I'm having is that the Docker daemon won't start, and I need it running at build time to be able to bake some Docker images onto the machine.

Is there a way to acquire an interactive shell to the EC2 build instance during the Packer build so I can debug what is going wrong with it? Until I figure out what is failing, I can't finish my work on this AMI.

Comment: I've never had the need to do so, but can't you just add one `sleep 1200` into provision script, and ssh into instance while it is waiting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `-debug` option to `packer build`:

```
packer build -debug something.json
```

This will cause packer to pause between steps, emit an IP address and a generated PEM certificate.

You can then do `ssh -i ec2_generated_key.pem centos@IP` and get into the box.